# Fading from one view to another without transitioning through black

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to fade one view in while fading the other out using `animateWithDuration` and changing the alpha values of each. The problem I'm having is that the views seem to fade through a black background. I would like to keep the transitioning background a white color being that both of my views have white backgrounds.

How can I fade between my two views without transitioning through a black background?

Here's my code:

```
[self.view1 setAlpha:0.0];
[self.view addSubview:self.view1];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{self.view1.alpha = 1.0;self.view2.alpha = 0.0;}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){[self.view2 removeFromSuperview];}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:0.4
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    [self.view addSubview:self.view1];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    [self.view2 removeFromSuperview];
                }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`

1. Set the new image view alpha to 0.
2. Place the new image view in front of the current image view.
3. In `animations:` set alpha of the new image view to 1.0.
4. In `completion:` handler cleanup how ever you want.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'm doing... the issue I'm running into is that it transitions through black for some reason. In other words, it fades between views appropriately, but the background gets dark as the animation happens. How do I prevent that?

Comment: The difference is that yopu are aminating the alpha of the back image so at half way through each image has an alp[ha of 0.5 and the background behind them is showing through and it iss black.

Comment: The background behind them is also white. I tried removing the `self.view2.alpha = 0.0;` in animations, but still the same issue.